# Sql Query to get the desired output

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Table

```
EmpName | Bonus
Rohit   | 20
Steve   | 35
Rohit   | 9
Johnson | 15
```

Now i want the user name and the sum bonus of distinct Employee who have bonus <30.
ANSWER should be;

```
EmpName | Sum(Bonus)
Rohit   | 29
Johnson | 15
```

What will be the Query to get this output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate function `sum()` to get the Total Bonus for each `empname` and then use a `HAVING` clause to return the `empname` that with a Total Bonus of less than 30:

```
select empname, sum(bonus) TotalBonus
from yt
group by empname
having sum(bonus) < 30;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c00e5/2)

Or if you want to only total those rows where the `bonus` is less than 30, you can use:

```
select empname, sum(bonus) TotalBonus
from yt
where bonus < 30
group by empname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c00e5/3)

Comment: Not the total bonus must be under 30 but bonus < 30 is not countet at all (imho). Edit +1

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was adding both because I don't know which one they wanted. :)

Comment: Thank a lot @TimSchmelter. This Having clause was not striking in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EmpName,
       SUM(Bonus) AS SumBonus
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE Bonus < 30
GROUP BY EmpName
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/670ba/3/0)